# How to use data from threads?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have a code on python with threadings but I don't know how to use the data (for example: `if (f(x) + g(y))<5)` from first and second threads. 
My output:

```
x 2
y 1
0 0
True
x 4
y 2
0 0
True
```

Expecting output:

```
x 2
y 1
2 1
True
x 4
y 2
4 2
False
```

My code:

```
import threading


def f(x, event_for_wait, event_for_set):
    for i in range(5):
        event_for_wait.wait()
        event_for_wait.clear()
        x = x + 2
        print("x",x)
        event_for_set.set()


def g(y, event_for_wait, event_for_set):
    for i in range(5):
        event_for_wait.wait()
        event_for_wait.clear()
        y = y + 1
        print("y",y)
        event_for_set.set()

def func (x , y, event_for_wait, event_for_set):
    for i in range(5):
        event_for_wait.wait()
        event_for_wait.clear()
        print(x, y)
        if x + y < 5:
            print(True)
            event_for_set.set()
        else:
            print(False)
            event_for_set.set()


x = 0
y = 0
# init events
e1 = threading.Event()
e2 = threading.Event()
e3 = threading.Event()
# init threads

t1 = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(x, e1, e2))

t2 = threading.Thread(target=g, args=(y, e2, e3))

t3 = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(x, y,  e3, e1))



t1.start()

t2.start()

t3.start()

e1.set() # initiate the first event
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you simply use a global variable. If you want to share the data of the variable thevar for example:
On the very top of your script:

```
thevar = 0
global thevar
```

And in every thread where thevar is used:

```
global thevar
```

That's it, now all threads can access thevar and store their computations there.